# .net Core 2.0 Assembly, with T4: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0

Tags: c#, t4, .net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0

I have a T4 template, I am referencing a different assembly I made like so:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)Project.CodeGen\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Project.CodeGen.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="Project.CodeGen" #>
```

I then try to create an instance of the only class in that dll:

```
var code = new CodeGenHelper();
```

When I run the T4 template (aka, save it), I get the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingCFC642B0A338D346F5BAF55401746E231DEE772554EE3570FFA3AA2898966BCA1378D2C2DC8325581610CA4D66B8A56C97E5C4A6AD35B2C18FAAAF37E1A6B7C9.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.PerformTransformation()
```

I then added a reference to

> System.Runtime

(fully qualified and not), and neither seemed to work.

This is what the Project.CodeGen source looks like (cut down):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace Project.CodeGen
{
    public class CodeGenHelper
    {
        public CodeGenHelper()
        {

        }

        public string Derp(string herp)
        {
            ... do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to reference System.Runtime somehow, I thought core was not able to?  Do I need to reference something like netstandard?  I'm confused to say the least.

Comment: Can you try upgrading the machine you develop on to .NET 4.7.2? This seems to be a limitation of the current T4 system but .NET 4.7.2 may work around it since it contains all netstandard forwarding assemblies.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing recently in a different project, but for this project discussed I ended up doing some Roslyn. Fun stuff!

Comment: @SteveStokes can you please elaborate on how you resolved this problem? Even today this seems to be an issue and I am a slowly running out of wisdom... My current guess is that assemblies built for > netstandard2.0 can't be loaded

Comment: @PaulMichalik that's correct, they cannot be loaded. The only way I was able to work around it was to no longer use T4 and use Roslyn to write code. I would encourage you to try it out, the solution ended up being more elegant and solid.

Comment: @SteveStokes I have tried almost everything but I could not strip it down to something which works across platforms and standard versions. I am still using T4 though, but I load shared code via include directives only.